# Overriding Method (Int => Int => Int) of Trait

Tags: scala

Given the following trait:

```
scala> trait Foo { 
     |   def f: Int => Int => Int
     | }
defined trait Foo
```

I created a class that tried to instantiate `Foo#f`:

```
scala> class FooImpl extends Foo {
     |  override def f(x: Int, y: Int) = 100
     | }
<console>:11: error: class FooImpl needs to be abstract, since method f in trait Foo of type => Int => (Int => Int) is not defined
       class FooImpl extends Foo {
             ^
```

I was able to resolve it with:

```
scala> class FooImpl extends Foo {
     |   override def f = x => y => 100
     | }
defined class FooImpl
```

Then I can make an instance:

```
scala> new FooImpl().f(10)(20)
res3: Int = 100
```

But, how would I create an implementation of `Foo` that implements `Foo#f` with `def f(x: Int, y: Int) = 100`, i.e. without currying?

Lastly, I tried:

```
scala> trait Bar { def f: (Int, Int) => Int }
defined trait Bar
```

But that failed too:

```
scala> class BarImpl extends Bar { 
     |  override def f(x: Int, y:Int) =100
     | }
<console>:11: error: class BarImpl needs to be abstract, since method f in trait Bar of type => (Int, Int) => Int is not defined
       class BarImpl extends Bar {
             ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those types are incompatible.

```
def f: Int => Int => Int
```

.. Is a *parameterless method* that returns a *function* with one argument `Int`, that returns a function with one argument `Int`, that returns `Int`.

```
def f: (Int, Int) => Int
```

.. Is a *parameterless method* that returns a *function* with two arguments of type `Int`, that returns `Int`.

```
def f(x: Int, y: Int): Int
```

.. Is a *two-parameter method* with two `Int` arguments that returns an `Int`.

All of these are fundamentally different. You cannot override any of them with any other. If you want `f(x: Int, y: Int): Int`, then that is the signature that should be in `Foo` in the first place. Otherwise, you'll have to curry, eta-expand, or something else to make the signatures match.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the trait to define the non-curried version, then it would need to be like this:

```
trait Foo {
  def f(x: Int, y: Int): Int
}
```

The `(x: Int, y: Int)` here says that `f` takes in two parameters of `Int` and the `: Int` says that the return value needs to be `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how can create `FooImpl` that implements `Foo` trait. We can also access Foo#f without currying.

```
trait Foo{
def f1:Int=> Int=> Int
def f2: (Int, Int) => Int
}

class FooImpl extends Foo{

    //actual implementors of f1 and f2 in Foo trait
    def g0=g1
    def g1=g2
    def g2=20
    def add(a:Int, b:Int)=a+b

    override  def f1=g0=>g1=>g2
    override def f2=add 
}
```

Now we can instantiate `FooImpl` class without currying.

```
var x = new FooImpl
println(x.f1.apply(1).apply(1))  //results 20
println(x.f2(10,10))             //results 20
```